# QWidget findChildren when objectname contains a specific string

Tags: c++, qt, find, qwidget

How do you list all childs from a qwidget that contain a specific string inside de objectname?

For example, if I have:

```
 "general_widget", with children:
    "label_name_1"
    "label__1"
    "label_name_2"
    "label_id_2"
    "label_name_3"
    "label_id_3"
    "label_name_4"
    "label_id_4"
```

I would like to get a list of all children that contain "name" as part of the objectName, and another list with all children that contain "id". Thanks!

Comment: [`QWidget::findChildren`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren-2)?

Comment: Yes, but what regular expression or pattern can I use so I get all of the ones that contain a specific string ("name" or "id")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a simple function like this:

```
QList<QWidget *> widgets(QWidget * parent, QString search)
{
    QRegularExpression exp(search);
    return parent->findChildren<QWidget *>(exp);
}
```

and given a `QWidget * widget` you can call it this way:

```
auto name_list = widgets(widget, "name");
auto id_list = widgets(widget, "id");
```

Comment: Useful to note that this overloaded function 
===

findChildren(const QRegularExpression &re, Qt::FindChildOptions options = Qt::FindChildrenRecursively) const

====
was introduced in Qt 5.0.

Comment: how do you get the `parent` widget to call this function?

Comment: @Bersan Pass `this` as the first argument?

Answer (score 2):

Use `findChildren()` along with  `objectName().contains()` , for example:

```
QList<QWidget*> subwidgets = this->findChildren<QWidget*>();
QListIterator<QWidget*> it(subwidgets); // iterate through the list of widgets
QWidget *awiget;

while (it.hasNext()) {
    awiget = it.next(); // take each widget in the list
    if (awiget->objectName().contains("name")){
        qDebug() << awiget->objectName();
    }
}
```